# Blender input file format: "File format is not supported in file" error

Tags: file-format

I have a file claimed to be Blender input. Perhaps it is only part of the input. I am having trouble running the blender GUI, so I am hoping to at least read the file into Blender on the command line (`-b`) to understand more about it - in a "bootstrapping" approach, as I am unfamiliar with Blender.

This website : http://otvinta.com/noncircular.html

Will produce what appears to be a Python file claimed to be a blender 2.8+ file. It should be easy to calculate one as needed - but I will put a part of the calculation output here, apologies if this volume is inappropriate :

```
 import bpy
 from math import *
 import math

 def createMeshFromData(name, origin, verts, edges, faces):
 # Create mesh and object
 me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name+'Mesh')
 ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
 ob.location = origin
 ob.show_name = False
 # Link object to scene and make active
 bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)
 ob.select_set(True)

 # Create mesh from given verts, faces.
 me.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)

 # Update mesh with new data
 me.update()

 C = 6.3094
 verts1 = 
 #[ sample code break]
```

Then there are lots of what in awk would be numbers of %1.6f format, "verts2", "Points1", "Points2" also with lots of those numbers, and then at the end of the file :

```
 #[ sample code resumes ]
 edges1 = [[len(verts1) - 1, 0]]
 for i in range( 0, len(verts1)-1):
 edges1.append( [i, i+1] )

 edges2 = [[len(verts2) - 1, 0]]
 for i in range( 0, len(verts2)-1):
 edges2.append( [i, i+1] )

 edgesPoint1 = [[len(Points1) - 1, 0]]
 for i in range( 0, len(Points1)-1):
 edgesPoint1.append( [i, i+1] )

 edgesPoint2 = [[len(Points2) - 1, 0]]
 for i in range( 0, len(Points2)-1):
 edgesPoint2.append( [i, i+1] )

 createMeshFromData( 'Pitch1', [0, 0, 0], verts1, edges1, [] )
 createMeshFromData( 'Pitch2', [0, C, 0], verts2, edges2, [] )
 createMeshFromData( 'Gear1', [0, 0, 0] , Points1, edgesPoint1, [] )
 createMeshFromData( 'Gear2', [0, C, 0] , Points2, edgesPoint2, [] )
```

I am interested in reading the file into Blender in the background, as I assume I can perhaps convert the file to something else. There is a tutorial as well, but it contains a binary file (I do not understand that either) - but it suggests the above file is missing something. Unfortunately, the YouTube tutorial video starts at the point when the Blender GUI is up and running, which is not an option for me at the moment :

http://otvinta.com/tutorial19.html

The error output from blender is:

```
 Error: File format is not supported in file 'my_file.blend'
```

I am not sure if this format is current for blender. I am frankly lost from reading about the different file conversions, import, export, and so on - but I am encouraged, as the documentation suggests a wide range of formats are possible for import and export :

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/import_export.html

I was hoping to learn starting from this particular file, as I am interested in the elliptical gear calculation. It appears the file I have is part of a larger input specification, but I do not understand how to provide this to blender - and I do not know where to start - it might mean finding another machine to do this on.

- Blender 3.0.1
- Ubuntu 22.04.1
- About 2.7 gig of RAM and an AMD Athlon dual core

Comment: Pass `-P your_file.py` on the command line.

Comment: ah, that eliminates the error. I passed `--render-frame 1` and it is running, FWIW.. I'll check later and see what happened...